# Capture user action on android permissions screen in a .NET MAUI project with C#?

Tags: c#, android, maui

I can already request permissions from the user in a .NET MAUI project, but now I need to perform specific actions as soon as the user clicks allow or disallow. That is, I need to run a routine as soon as the permissions display is closed.
From what I've read in Xamarin there is OnRequestPermissionsResult method which seems to do the job. However in MAUI it seems that this method is not available.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check the [PermissionStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=windows#permission-status)

```
PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
{
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can request permissions by following code:

```
PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.>();
```

And after accepting or denying the requirement ,the user's behavior can be detected by the returned status `status`.

You can refer to the following code:

```
async Task RequestBluetooth() 
    {
        if (DeviceInfo.Platform != DevicePlatform.Android)
            return;

        var status = PermissionStatus.Unknown;

        if(DeviceInfo.Version.Major >= 12)
        {
            status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<MyBluetoothPermission>();

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                return;

            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<MyBluetoothPermission>())
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Needs permissions", "BECAUSE!!!", "OK");
            }

            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<MyBluetoothPermission>();


        }
        else
        {
            status = await Permissions.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
                return;

            if (Permissions.ShouldShowRationale<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>())
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Needs permissions", "BECAUSE!!!", "OK");
            }

            status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();


        }

        if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
  // if you click the accept button
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Permission required",
                " permission is Granted. " , "OK");

        else if (status == PermissionStatus.Denied)
        {// if you click the deny button
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Permission required",
                " permission is denied. " , "OK");

        }
    }
```

And you can get the full sample [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MauiApp-DI).

For the tutorial for it, please check [Accessing Native Platform APIs in .NET MAUI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JCgxK0pWjNg)